# Согласование сказуемого с 21 тысяча

Tags: согласование, числительные

В предложении "Приняли участие 21 561 человек" верно согласование сказуемого? Или "ПринялА участие двадцать одна тысяча"?..

Comment: *ПринялА участие* - О Господи! .. Ну это ж нарочно не придумаешь...

Comment: А что вы предлагаете со словом тысяча?

Comment: В вашем примере со словом "тысяча" я ничего не предлагаю. Я предлагаю посмотреть учебник класс этак за седьмой. Я бы еще понял, предложи вы выбор из вариантов ***приняло/приняли/принял участие 21 561 человек".